# PCB Layout review: ESP-07 with 28BYJ-48 Stepper board

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly, review

I have used the 28BYJ-48 in conjunction with an ESP8266 in some applications and I thought it would be handy to have pcb made. I want to use JLCPCB including Pick and Place.

The Kicad source code is on [github.com/besi/stepomatic](https://github.com/besi/stepomatic)

[image: schematic]
[image: the front populated]
[image: the front without components]
[image: the Back]
[image: pcbnew]
[image: front assembly]
[image: front copper]
[image: back copper]

Known issues

- Using USB and ESP8266 might (temporarily) use too much power
- I did remove the reference designators for aesthetic reasons, which is, I admit, not ideal for a review. My apologies.
- I have to add some test points

Comment: The ULN will produce a lot of noise at pin 9 (+5 V) and the capacitor, that should catch that (C2), is at the other end of the board.